# What are the differences between the SOQL filter statements and when should they be used?

Tags: soql

[Salesforce Object Query Language](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) (SOQL) has a variety of statements that can be used to filter result sets. Some of these statements appear to do the same type of filtering but they must all exist for a reason and some are better documented than others.

What are the differences between the SOQL filter statements and when should they be used? 
(or not used, or used in conjunction with each other?)

- [WHERE](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm)
- [USING SCOPE](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_using_scope.htm)
- [WITH](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with.htm)
- [WITH DATA CATEGORY](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with_datacategory.htm)
- [HAVING](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I did pull a lot of this from the links, but for starters:

- WHERE - General use in SOQL, pretty straightforward how it is used.
- USING SCOPE - Never heard of this one and it is quite horribly documented.
- WITH - Apparently this is specific to either UserProfileFeed or Knowledge articles.
- WITH DATA CATEGORY - Specific to Knowledge articles.
- HAVING - Specific to Aggregate queries.

Examples:

WHERE

```
SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY
```

WITH

```
SELECT Id
FROM UserProfileFeed
WITH UserId='005D0000001AamR'
```

WITH DATA CATEGORY

```
SELECT Title
FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion
WITH DATA CATEGORY Geography__c ABOVE usa__c
```

HAVING

```
SELECT Name, Count(Id)
FROM Account
GROUP BY Name
HAVING Count(Id) > 1
```

**EDIT**

I found [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm) which is also somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @adrianlarson's answer

`USING SCOPE` is actually pretty cool and [is documented here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000204543&language=en_US).

An example is to get all Opportunities for the running user's territory (assuming you are using territory management)

```
select id, ... from Opportunity Where ... USING SCOPE My_Territory
```

It is a SOQL solution to those OOB queries provided in list views and reports (my team, my territories, etc.).

> filterScope_value can take one of the following enumeration values: Everything, Mine, My_Territory, My_Team_Territory or Team

Comment: Thanks for adding this detail. Very helpful! It's disappointing to see that the official docs don't list the acceptable values but the Knowledge Article does. Updated the answer with the list for posterity.

Comment: @MarkPond - I know, I stumbled across this when trying to figure out the SOQL for a custom mobile app that needed to do 'My Territories' query as running user was an overlay specialist, opportunity teams weren't being used and running user was not the oppo owner. Documentation is woeful, I agree.