# Difference between WITH and WHERE Filter conditions in QUERY?

Tags: soql, query, sosl

Could you please someone let me know more about WITH and when its used as I came to know about it recently. I know WHERE and when and how its used. But when exactly WITH is used when compared to WHERE. Whether WITH can be used for all Std & Custom Object Fields.

I got something from below link but not able to find a usecase on it. If  someone can explain it with an example that will be great.

[Filters used in SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75597/what-are-the-differences-between-the-soql-filter-statements-and-when-should-they)

Comment: What are you having trouble understanding that the documentation does not provide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference is quite clear on the constraints of the `WITH` filter expression:

> The WITH clause can only be used in the following cases:
>
> - To filter records based on their categorization. See [WITH DATA CATEGORY filteringExpression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with_datacategory.htm#topic-title).
> - To query and retrieve record changes tracked in a user profile feed. See UserProfileFeed in the [Object Reference for Salesforce and Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/).

So unless you are querying the `UserProfileFeed` object, it is only usable for data categories.

Comment: You beat me to it.